# SCILAB - Undefined operation for the given operands

Tags: scilab

I am having a problem with scilab. At line "A=(f(a)+f(b))/2;" it gives me an error:

in builtin                f

Undefined operation for the given operands.
check or define function %fptr_p_s for overloading.

Here are my codes:

```
function fx=f(x);
fx=4.*x^2.+3*exp^-x-4*cos*(1.5*x);
endfunction;
a=0;
b=2;
n=10; //sub interval
dx=(b-a)/n;
A=(f(a)+f(b))/2;
for k=1:(N-1)
A=A+f(a+k*dx);
end;
I=A*dx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    fx = 4.*x^2. + 3*exp^-x - 4*cos*(1.5*x);
```

I guess you mean

```
    fx = 4.*x^2. + 3*exp(-x) - 4*cos(1.5*x);
```

You can't put a function to a power, or multiply it by something.
You do that with its result, not with it.